# How to fix views ajax problem when accessing via a proxy? (Browser Sync)

Tags: views, theming

I am using a new theme called Neato which uses node.js to run gulp and Browser Sync.

For dynamic sites, Browser Sync has to run in proxy mode and the live preview is then displayed at http://localhost:3000/

However, this setup causes an error when configuring a view - as follows;

```
The page at localhost:3000 says:

An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: to view
StatusText: error
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 0
```

I find that the error happens when using a views modal, such as when configuring some row settings and occurs after choosing to save or cancel. It is not possible to update the view from this situation and the only way to close the modal is via (x) button.

The error does not happen when accessing the site in the normal way via localhost and only when using the Browser Sync proxy?

Can anything be done to allow trouble free use of views when accessing via a proxy and more specifically when using Browser Sync.

Possibly related (and quite funny) - https://www.drupal.org/node/1069800

Related Links:

http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy

https://www.drupal.org/project/neato

I tried to add a tag for Browser Sync but don't have enough reputation.

---

### Edit. Related drupal.org url corrected.

Comment: Are you sure you've linked to the right D.o issue? That one seems to be about a bug in the feedparser module from version 4.7 ;)

Comment: Maybe it needs another '0' at the end? https://www.drupal.org/node/1069800 though that's for Views 2...

Comment: Clive is correct and I have now edited the url accordingly. Yes it is Views 2 but the error message is the same.  Likewise the d.o post focuses on the url being a contributory factor to the problem.